# Iphone simulator not reset it's content.How to reset it?

Tags: ios, iphone, ios-simulator, xcode8, macos-sierra

I'm using xcode 8 it works fine but when I try to reset simulator using

```
In the iOS Simulator, press iOS Simulator in the menu at the top of the screen, 
and press 'Reset Content and Settings...'. This should clear the entire simulator.But it gives below error.
```

[image: snap 2]

Then i try using Terminal and get same error like below

[image: snap 1]

Please help me with this issue thanks in advance.

Comment: Make sure that you are admin of the system. Clear all the derived data also

Comment: Does the complete error mention the affected file?

Comment: The path of `data` would be ~/Library/Developer/CoreSimulator/Devices/[UDID]/data ... you should check what the permisisons are and figure out why you can't delete it.

Comment: @GouravJoshi Yes i'm admin of system and already tried with clearing derived data..

Comment: @shallowThought Every time it gives same error that shown in Image attached above.

Comment: @JeremyHuddlestonSequoia I checked there i can see there is read and write permission assign.

Comment: I would first check the permissions of the mentioned file (like stated in the error) and maybe try to force the directories permissions: `sudo chmod -R 775  ~/Library/Developer/CoreSimulator/Devices/`.

Answer (score 2):

May be its not the answer you expect, However it will help you when you not get proper answer.

Delete that simulator from Xcode-> Window-> Devices and add new simulator of same target.
I hope may be it will work like we reset the simulator.